# view linebreak symbol

Tags: notebooks, formatting, style, procedural-programming

[image]

As you see in the above example, **In[294] and In[295]** **looks just the same, but the outputs are different.**
The fact is that there is no linebreak symbol in In[294], but there is one linebreak symbol in In[295].
(There is a linebreak between Goto["End"] and Label["End"] in  In[295].)
The above example was screen-shoted when mathematica notebook width was decreased with a setting 'format - word wrapping - wrap at windows width'.
So **the linebreak in In[295] is completely unnoticeable**.

In text editor like notepad++, there is an option to **view line break symbols**. Is there a such option for mathematica?

Comment: Not an answer, just noting that it's a good idea to parenthesize such expressions so that you don't need to rely on the absence of a newline.

Comment: Yes parenthesizing is one of the solution (I  knew it today from other question!) but I want to see line break symbols.

Comment: I think this is the second question where you encounter problems which are related to `Goto`. It seems an obvious indication that you find problems because you use Mathematica in a way it is not actually meant to be used. Can you explain why you insist in using `Goto`? I would consider it strongly unrecommened to use `Goto` in Mathematica and have not used it a single time in my 25 years of extensive usage of Mathematica...

Comment: Thank you experienced, and advanced user. I feel the same in most way but there is a reason why I stick to Goto. I feel Goto is the most fundamental, can to do everything... may be I will write about this when my thoughts are organized.